# rtsp support on iPhone and how to develop application to use live streaming through RTSP

Tags: iphone

I have a server that supports RTSP. Through my application on the iPhone I want to do live streaming using the RTSP protocol. Is this supported on the iPhone?

If not can I create my own RTSP protocol and will Apple allow me to put this app on the app store?

Thanks,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this if it helps, u might have read this..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html