# Not Playing RTSP live stream in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios4, rtsp, live-streaming, rtsp-client

I have worked with streaming HTTP live streaming. Now I want to try with RTSP live streaming.

But not getting much tutorials or any sample code to get started.

Also got [Github link of projec](https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone) dropCam but it is not being run so that I can see how to stream RTSP.

Also go through [Stackoverflow questions1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019841/stream-live-video-from-ip-cams-in-iphone-sdk) , [questions2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927521/rtsp-support-on-iphone-and-how-to-develop-application-to-use-live-streaming-thro) but still blank.

Till Now I have try,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://video3.americafree.tv/AFTVComedyH2641000.sdp"];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://10.2.216.228:554/2G/LIVE/STARPLUS_QCIF.sdp"];

    mpVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:mpVC.view];
```

But Not Playing.

Any nice tutorial with sample code or elaborated information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Iphone doesn't support rtsp streaming protocol.
You should try it by using third party libraries such as FFmpeg.
FFmpeg library has some feature that help you play rtsp streaming.

I'll post helpful url that specifies how to play mms streaming protocol using FFmpeg.

[this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.ffmpeg.libav.user/5475)